# Screen tearing while gaming

Tags: macos, graphics

I'm running an iMac with a 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7 with 12 GB of DDR3 on OS X 10.9.5 and am getting tearing with playing CS:GO. I'd like to fix this. How can I disable Vsync in 10.9.5? What does this have to do with [Beamsync?](http://www.tonymacx86.com/threads/beamsyncdropper-tool-to-disable-beamsync-permanently.92201/)

Answer (score 1):

CS:GO respects its own Vsync setting, which works while in fullscreen. You can edit this in the Video options:

[image]

Enabling this setting will prevent screen tearing, at the cost of performance. Typically, this is undesirable in a competitive game like CS:GO, but there's nothing stopping you.

Beamsync is Apple's implementation of Vsync, present in the normal desktop environment and, by default, most apps. As of OS X Mavericks, the ability to enable/disable it [was accessible through the Graphics Tools for Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345730/how-to-disable-vsync-on-macos):

> - [Download Graphics Tools for Xcode - Late August 2014](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDNWW.png)
> - Install or just mount **Graphic Tools**
> - Open **Quartz Debug**
> - Go to Tools -> Show Beam Sync Tools
> - Select Disable Beam Synchronization

Note that these changes are not permanent.

At some point however, [this appears to have changed](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/topic/319473-beam-sync/): [disabling Beam Sync is no longer available through the Graphics Tools.](https://www.reddit.com/r/macgaming/comments/3l3mp2/anyone_know_how_to_turn_off_beamsync_on_el_capitan/) Some tools ([1](https://github.com/satoruhiga/ofxBeamSyncDropper) and [2](https://github.com/andreydev/Mac-VSync-BeamSync-Switcher)) claim to disable it, but I haven't verified their integrity, and neither have been updated since 2015.

My recommendation given your use case is to just keep CS:GO in fullscreen and use their implementation of Vsync, toggling as you see fit.